# Auto launch Chromium extension on launch

Tags: google-chrome-extension, raspberry-pi, chromium

I have a Raspberry Pi and I want it to auto launch Chromium in fullscreen when it boots up. I also want to auto launch the Rotisserie URL Rotator as soon as Chromium loads so it will start rotating through my default tabs automatically.

I've looked into the extension's manifest.json and there is the section for "background" but I am not sure what I'm supposed to do in order to get the extension to auto launch.

Comment: chrome.tabs.create({url: '/relative-page-file-path-name-in-the-extension-package.html'})

Comment: Would I put this in the autostart file located here?

/home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart

Or in the extensions manifest file?

Comment: No, in background.js

Comment: It's not Pi-specific, it's declared in your extension's manifest.json and is inside the extension directory. See https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages

Comment: Okay I've added that line to a file called "background.js" and placed that in the extensions directory. Then I declared it in the extension's manifest.json file but it doesn't appear to be auto-starting the extension when I load up Chromium. 

What am I missing?

Comment: Try debugging the extension's background page, see [Where to read console messages from background.js in a Chrome extension?](//stackoverflow.com/a/10258029)

Comment: unfortunately there doesn't seem to be anything appearing in the debug console. There are a lot of people in the Extension's comment section requesting an "autolaunch" feature, apparently it's in high demand. There really isn't an easy way to get it working?